# JQuery to removeClass of all links within an element

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I've got my selectors wrong. I am trying to select all elements within a class that are links and remove a class from them.

I tried this to no avail.

```
$('.panel:a').removeClass('active');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.panel a').removeClass('active');//Will remove class 'active' from all elements comes under elements that've class panel
$('.panel > a').removeClass('active'); // Will remove class only from immediate children
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$('a.panel').removeClass('active'); 
//removes active from all anchor tags with class panel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    var objs = $('.panel');

    $.each(objs, function(key, obj){
        if(obj.is('a')){
            obj.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Does that help?